# How to Disallow User Access to CRUD Backend

Tags: laravel-backpack

I've got Backpack for Laravel installed and have been using it for some time as an admin back end on a project. I'm also using the [spatie/permission module](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) (might come with Backpack, can't remember) to create users for the front end.

Currently, all users are able to access both front end and back end regardless of the group they belong to. I'd like to change that so that only members in an "admin" group are able to access the back end. I've followed [the instructions here](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.4/docs/frequently-asked-questions#section-use-separate-sessions-for-adminuser-authentication) for separating front end and back end sessions but that's not really what I want as all users are still able to access both sides of the project.

I'm guessing I need to add a guard to the CRUD routes but I'm finding it to be much harder than it should be. Any pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new middleware and use it in your routes group for admin routes.

To create a new middleware use the `php artisan` command like so: (you can name the new middleware what ever you want:

`php artisan make:middleware RequireAdminRole`

Now, inside your new middleware, on the `handle` function you can have something like this that returns a 403 Forbidden error message:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $user = auth()->user();

    if (!$user) return $next($request);

    if (!$user->hasRole('Admin'))
    {
        // if your sessions are decoupled from the frontend
        // you can even logout the user like so:
        // auth()->logout();

        abort(403, 'Access denied');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Here we are using the hasRole method, but there are more that you can use. [See the spatie/laravel-permissions documentation for more info.](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-permissions-via-roles)

Now, let's assign this middleware a 'name' so we can use it in our route groups for the admin. Inside the `App\Kernel.php` file, in the end, inside the `$routeMiddleware` array add it and give it a new, for example:

`'isadmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RequireAdminRole::class,`

And finally, you can add this middleware to your admin routes group (which should be in `custom.php` file if you're using latest backpack 3.4 version) :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    'middleware' => ['web', 'isadmin', config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')],
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () {
    // your routes are here
});
```

Now all your requests to the admin routes should be protected by the user role check.

Please let us know how it went for you, and if you encountered any issues.

Best regards,

~Cristian

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the clear instructions. We suspected it would be something like this but weren't sure of the details.